# NuGet package installation fail

Tags: model-view-controller, nuget, nuget-package

I created NuGet package and try to install this package. In during instalation I get error:
"Name cannot begin with the '~' character, hexadecimal value 0x7E. Line 6, position 31."

My package consist _Layout.cshtml (with _Layout.cshtml.transform name) file with following content:

```
<head>
    @RenderSection("ReportsHeader", false);   
</head>
```

When I deleted this file the package was installed success.

in mvc project in _Layout.cshtml file in head tag:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

If I deleted

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

package installed but _Layout.cshtml file not modified.

How I can modify _Layout.cshtml file ?

or my be I can modify _Layout.cshtml file in install.ps1 file ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with your quotation marks. Try using ' instead of " for the inner quotable sections something like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content('~/Content/Site.css')" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content('~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js')" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content('~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js')" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Not sure if that syntax will work, but the use of nested " quotes looks like trouble.